# Window is not closing properly second time

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I want to open a new window on click of button. On cclick on button window is opening and closing fine but second time it is not closing properly.

**Here is my code**

```
var formPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
    height: 125,
    autoScroll: true,
    id: 'formpanel',
    defaultType: 'field',
    frame: true,
    title: 'CheckOut from SVN',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'SVN Path'
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Submit',
        minWidth: 75,
        handler: function() {

            var urlTemp = './Export?' + '&' + fp.getForm().getValues(true);
            formPanel.getForm().submit({
                url: urlTemp,
                method: 'Post',
                success: successFn1,
                timeout: 18000000,
                failure: otherFn
            });
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Reset',
        minWidth: 75,
        handler: function() {
            formPanel.getForm().reset();
        }
    }]
});


function buildWindow() {

    var win = new Ext.Window({
        id: 'newWindow',
        layout: 'fit',
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        closeAction: 'hide',
        plain: true,
        stateful: false,
        items: [formPanel]
    });

    win.show();
}

var extSVN = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Checkout from SVN',
    minWidth: 75,
    handler: function() {
        buildWindow();
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    items: [extSVN]
});
```

Comment: What are you doing to close the window?

Comment: Put your code into a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com).

Comment: clicking on close icon(cross or 'x' button of window)

Comment: Try changing **closeAction** to 'destroy' instead of 'hide'.

Answer (score 0):

you are using  `closeAction: 'hide'` on your window which mean that when you close it it will not be destroyed but hidden.
The problem is that when you reopen the window you create a new one so your formPanel ends up in 2 different windows which causes the error.

You can :

- remove the `closeAction: 'hide'`, but your formPanel will also be
  destroy when you close the window, so you'll have to recreate
  another too
- or keep the `closeAction: 'hide'` and only create the
  windows one time

Answer (score 0):

You have provided `id` to your `form` and `window`. And inside window you have set config `closeAction: 'hide'` that means whenever your press close button `window` is hiding.

And on again on-click of `Checkout from SVN` button you creating a same `window` and `form` with same `id's` so instead of creating of new `window` you can use previous window and show again.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2evm)**, I have created a demo using your code and put some modifications.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var formPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
        height: 125,
        autoScroll: true,
        id: 'formpanel',
        defaultType: 'field',
        frame: true,
        title: 'CheckOut from SVN',
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'SVN Path'
        }],
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Submit',
            minWidth: 75,
            handler: function () {

                var urlTemp = './Export?' + '&' + fp.getForm().getValues(true);
                formPanel.getForm().submit({
                    url: urlTemp,
                    method: 'Post',
                    success: successFn1,
                    timeout: 18000000,
                    failure: otherFn
                });
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Reset',
            minWidth: 75,
            handler: function () {
                formPanel.getForm().reset();
            }
        }]
    });

    function buildWindow(btn) {
        if (!btn.win) {
            btn.win = new Ext.Window({

                layout: 'fit',

                id: 'newWindow',

                modal: true,

                width: 300,

                height: 200,

                closeAction: 'hide',

                plain: true,

                stateful: false,

                items: [formPanel]
            });
        }

        btn.win.show();
    }

    var extSVN = new Ext.Button({
        text: 'Checkout from SVN',
        minWidth: 75,
        handler: buildWindow
    });

    new Ext.Panel({
        title: 'SVN Chekcout',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 200,
        height: 130,
        items: [extSVN],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```